# How do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance tasks work and how can I automate them?

Tags: macos, automation, maintenance

MacOS comes with daily/weekly/monthly system tasks. However it looks like I have to manually start those tasks. Is there a way to automatically have those tasks executed daily/weekly/monthly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are named like this because *they are already executed daily, weekly and monthly*. MainMenu just lets you execute them manually.

Open Terminal and enter the following:

```
ls -al /var/log/*.out
```

The dates listed next to these log file names are when the respective maintenance task was last executed:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  496994  5 Mar 03:15 /var/log/daily.out
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    2088  1 Mar 06:02 /var/log/monthly.out
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    5289  5 Mar 03:15 /var/log/weekly.out
```

---

Run them manually using the `periodic` command. You need `root` permissions to do so, and need to supply which you want to execute. To run all of them:

```
sudo periodic daily weekly monthly
```

You can use AppleScript Editor to make a Script or Application that executes e.g. the weekly task by entering this:

```
do shell script "periodic weekly" with administrator privileges
```

Using Automator, you can make it into a service.

---

To change when these tasks are regularly scheduled, edit their preference files:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-weekly.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-monthly.plist
```

You can use *Property List Editor* included with Apple's Developer Tools, or a simple text editor. Look for `<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>`. When they're running is pretty self-explanatory:

Daily runs at 3:15 AM if it can:

```
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
</dict>
```

Once a week runs Saturday:

```
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
    <key>Weekday</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
</dict>
```

Once a month on the first day of the month:

```
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
    <key>Day</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
```

---

[This website](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/maintscripts.html) explains what happens when these scripts are run.